# Can't Update Yosemite "Show Details" loop

Tags: macos, software-update, developer-program

I was on the Yosemite Developer Preview all summer and now I can't install `OS X Yosemite Developer Preview 7 1.0`

1) It alerts me that there is an update (everyday)

2) I open the App Store and click Updates

3) `OS X Yosemite Developer Preview 7 1.0` is listed as available

4) Click `UPDATE`

5) `Restarting Your Computer` prompt appears and I click restart

6) `Available updates have changed` appears and when I click `Show Details` the alert hides

7) Back to step 3

Any help would appreciated

Comment: As the official release is out, why don't you try with it? I meant search for Yosemite 10.10 on App Store download and try to update from that version.

Comment: @jherran - I tried that. I have also left the beta program and I'm still stuck in the same loop with this developer preview